# Why strcmp seems not to work with a string returned by strtok?

Tags: c, strtok, strcmp

So, I have some code like:

```
char* t2 = strtok(NULL, " \t\n,");
char regN[3];
strcpy(regN, t2);
Register* rt = getRegister(regN);
```

I checked several times the value of `regN` by printing is `$t0` but the function returns `NULL`.
However when I tried `getRegister("$t0")` it returns the correct value.
The only reason I can think for this is if `strtok()` returns something other than the predicted value. Yes, the next token is `$t0`. I checked this as well.
Any suggestions or ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: How do you know the returned token will be 2-element long only?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `char* t2 = strtok(NULL, " \t\n,");` to return? Please make an [mre].

Comment: The second and third lines are of no value, and in fact (as the next comment explains) they may be harmful. You can simply pass `t2` to `getRegister`.

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, and the next token is `"$t0"`, then that's too long for `regN` (which can only hold a null-terminated string of max. 2 characters long, not 3). Hence, [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) ...

Comment: What is `getRegister()`? Did you call `strtok()` before? On what input string? What do you mean by `getRegister("$t0")`? There is no `strcmp()` in the shown code, yet your question is about it. So, please, provide an MRE.

Answer (score 2):

Three char long string must be stored in the 4 char array as it also needs the space for terminating zero. Your array is 3 chars long, so you have the Undefined Behaviour here